# Prusa i3MK3S+ layer skip with polycarbonate (overheating?)

Tags: prusa-i3, adhesion, underextrusion, filament-jam, polycarbonate

On the last couple of polycarbonate prints with my Prusa, one or more layers have been completely skipped (i.e. no material extruded). The rest of the print is fine save some minor warping. I'm printing in an enclosure that gets up to ~60 °C with the power supply outside the enclosure. I'm also printing out of a dry box with a fairly long bowden tube. I suspect it has something to do with overheating because this doesn't happen when I print without an enclosure.

I cracked the print in half just to take a look in between the layers.[image: Side view]

[image: Bottom piece][image: Top piece]

Comment: If you print the same thing twice, does it skip the same layer or random layers?

Comment: 60 deg C in an enclosure seems really hot, can the rest of the parts in there handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just ruining the PETG parts that held the extruder gears. They didn't really melt but got soft and crept really badly. I replaced them with new parts everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing overheating, consider to provide input/output airflow to the enclosure for the controller board and for the power supply. I've seen elsewhere on the 'net (forgotten locations) of Prusa printers with DIY extensions to the cables that are used in those components, allowing them to be located outside, with ambient airflow.

Comment: The power supply is outside the enclosure but not the board.

Comment: I think you have at least a partial answer in your comment.